# Entity Framework Error: The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

this is my first time asking a question in StackOverflow even though I've been reading and using the forum for at least a year so bear with me.

I'm working on a side project and I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks. I can't narrow down the problem and I've tried tons of different solutions posted on the net but none of them seem to solve it for me.

### Error

> The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

### Symptoms

- I can tell the problem happens when EntityFramework functions are called, especially SaveChanges but it also happens by Find
- I believe this problem started happening when I renamed a table in the database (its Code First but I can't delete the Database because I cant lose the data.). Migrations created a huge script which partially ran, I commented sections of it until it worked. Im beginning to think this is the source of all my problems but I still cant find the reason. With what little knowledge I have, I've made sure the tables have their Primary Keys set and they do ([InvalidOperationException: The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519848/invalidoperationexception-the-property-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information)).

### Questions

- First of all, why am I getting this error when I'm only trying to fetch record from the Database?
- What other things should I be looking at?

## Code Examples

### SaveChanges

```
public CandidatoDetail Get(Guid id)
{
    return _dbContext.CandidatoDetails.Include("Nacionalidad").SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
}
```

### Find

```
public Procedencia Get(Guid id)
{
    return _dbContext.Procedencias.Find(id);
}
```

### Procedencia Entity

```
namespace GAdUPIN.CORE.Domain
{
    public class Procedencia
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Canal de procedencia")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe incluir el nombre de la procedencia")]
        public string NombreProcedencia { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

I've tried most of the answers that show up on google from stack overflow and many other forums that seemed to point me in the right direction but to no avail. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: What line is getting the exception?

Comment: Hi, sorry I left you hanging. I had a couple weeks of pretty stressful work and couldn't pick it back up. It might not be the best solution for others with the same problem but I upgraded my solution from Visual Studio 2010 (which used Entity Framework 4.0) to Visual Studio 2015, which in turn had also forced me to upgrade my Entity Framework to 6.0. 

I know it's not be most optimal solution, but for others who have tried everything, this might be another thing to try out. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting the comment I gave @jeff-siver as how I found a workaround for the problem. It doesn's actually find the source of the problem but it makes it go away.

It might not be the best solution for others with the same problem but I upgraded my solution from Visual Studio 2010 (which used `Entity Framework 4.0`) to Visual Studio 2015, which in turn had also forced me to upgrade my `Entity Framework to 6.0`.

I know it's not be most optimal solution, but for others who have tried everything, this might be another thing to try out.